# Gallaxy S3 recharging prob-Master reset? will I loose contacts?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3

I've had a Gallaxy S3 for a little over one year without problems. All of the sudden it won't charge up. Barely to anything after being turned off and plugged in for hours! I've switched chargers, even tried usb to PC, switched batteries with my husband, same problem. It's my phone, not the battery. I've done a cach partition wipe. No change. NOW...to my question. I am looking at doing a master reset. Will I loose my contacts and pictures?? Thank you for helping me. Can't afford a new phone at this time.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, a master reset will wipe your downloaded apps and personal data.

You could backup your photo's on your PC. Another option would be Google Drive or any other cloud service.

Your contacts you can open contacts under settings. There should be import/export option. Then you can export them to your sim card or what every option is available. Also another option that maybe available is to save them to your Google or Samsung account.

Comment: Ok, thank you soooo much!! How do I back up my contacts, please?

Comment: Can I remove my SIM card before a master reset to keep my contacts??

Comment: I just watched this video and it instructs me to back up to SD card. Is the SD card the same as a SIM card and should it be removed prior to master reset?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=spAY40G49Jw

Comment: No an SD card is different than a sim card. You can move it if you wish. the sim card should not be messed with by the master reset just the device.